# Display content dynamically with Dropdown (with connection to DB)

Tags: javascript, ajax, dropdown

im pretty new into this stuff and I just tried to do an AJAX request with Javascript and PDO and PHP to create a dropdown function that reacts dynamically in order to display new content.. Since my knowledge is quite limited here I created it by combining snippets of code I got from various pages and videos. The error is:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'endforeach' (T_ENDFOREACH) in /var/www/xxx/html/listing.php on line 22
```

This is my listing.php page where the dropdown and the new content should be displayed:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>listing</title>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<meta name="keywords" content="">

<link href=".css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" rel="shortcut icon">
</head>

<body>

<select name="user" id="user-select">

<option value="">Choose a user</option>
<?php foreach ($subjects->fetchAll() as $user); ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $user['subject_id']; ?>"><?php echo $user['subject']; ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>

</select>

<div id="user-profile"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/global.js"></script>
```

This is the global.js file:

```
$('#user-select').on('change', function() {
var self = $(this);

$.ajax({
    url: 'https://www.xxx.de/partials/user.php',
    type: 'GET',
    data: { user: self.val() },
    success: function(data){
      $('#user-profile').html(data);
    }
});
});
```

And the partials/user.php, which contains the connection to the database:

```
<?php
$dsn = "xxx";
$user = "xxx";
$pw = "xxx";

try {
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pw);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

if (isset($_GET['user'])) {
$userQuery = "
SELECT
    subjects.subject_id,
    subjects.subject,
FROM subjects
WHERE subjects.subject_id = :subject_id
";

$user = $pdo->prepare($userQuery);
$user->execute(['subject_id' => $_GET['user']]);

$selectedUser = $user->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

print_r($selectedUser);
}
?>
```

Any help is appreciated and I am thankful for any tips !

Answer (score 1):

Stupid mistake.. I simply forgot to include the connection on the listing.php page to fill the foreach loop. 
->

On listing.php before the !DOCTYPE html begins:

```
<?php
$dsn = "xxx";
$user = "xxx";
$pw = "xxx";

try {
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pw);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

$usersQuery = "SELECT fach_id, fach FROM faecher";

$users = $pdo->query($usersQuery);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing ; with : in php foreach statement

```
<?php foreach ($subjects->fetchAll() as $user): ?>
```

Comment: Hi Leadfoot, thanks for you help. I guess this was also the mistake - see below what I've done wrong/have forgotten besides the ";" instead of the ":" behind the foreach loop. Really appreciate that you helped me :)